# Best way to read text file without hogging memory

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, vector

What is the best way to read a textfile say for example i have a textfile that contains several hundred books. Under those books would be authors ect some authors can have multiple books.

How would i write this program so it would not read the entire file into memory (array, vector, etc) when searching or finding a piece of info. Say i type in the authors name and it finds every book they wrote. So I am curious about the best way and most efficient way to do this.

I would code this in C++

Comment: If you are searching for all of an authors book, you will have to load the whole file anyway (as a worst case scenario)

Comment: Don't use a text file when you need a database.  You can use them in C++ as well, it doesn't require Java.  Consider sqlite for example.

Answer (score 0):

The basic answer is a FileStream. So you seek a location in your file on disk and then read from there. However you are going to very disk io bound at that point and your file must conform to some structure unless you want to have to read from start to target every time you want to find something. ie it would have to be in author order, which might even if acceptable would mean a search through it for anything else would be wildly inefficient.

Classic approach to you problem would be index files.
So books.dat would a related authors.idx which would say be a list of authors and titles preferably sorted by author.
Then you have titles.idx which is Title and the position the book starts at in books.dat.
The next title in the file would give you the length of the book.

Of course you have to maintain both files. If the application doesn't edite the file then tooling uo to create the indexes you require would be a good way to go.